# Input type of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an android app which get complex number from user as a input. I am using `EditText` for this purpose. What my doubt is I am using input type as both the number and decimal. I want to add extra character named "i"(for complex) in the `EditText` widget.

For Example I want add below complex as input.How to bring this "i" in soft keyboard??

```
5 + i 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML where you created your EditText, you can set the input type to include text as well as follows:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|text"
```

Be aware this will allow the user to store other alphabets - you might want to do some additional checks at run time to prevent this.

Comment: There are two ways of doing this - one would be to get the input from the user and then extract the string and do a verification or to add an addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()) and override the onTextChanged() method of TextWatcher to not accept anything other than numbers and an i. The logic for TextWatcher will be somewhat convoluted and it will be easier to use the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try also writing such filter for EditText:

```
public class ComplexNumbersFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char character = source.charAt(i);

            if (!(Character.isDigit(character) || character == 'i')) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And then in Activity (or Fragment or somewhere):

```
complexEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new ComplexNumbersFilter() });
```

If you are typing in whole mathematical operation you should add also math symbols to filter (+,-,/,*, etc)

Comment: I think you should return `source.subSequence(start, i-1);` instead of `""`.

Answer (score 0):

[InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) would be a way to go, but I think the easiest solution is to set:

```
android:digits="0123456789i"
```